# Fervor of Battle vs Thunderlord's Decree on Kindred

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been playing pretty much only Kindred since the start of this season but I have yet to try Thunderlords on her. So far I've been going only with Fervor of Battle which seems to be working out pretty well.

So I was wondering if Thunderlord's is worth giving it a try or Fervor of Battle is flat out better.

I am poking the enemy pretty often so Fervor of Battle does get proc-ed but I rarely ever poke them more than two-three times unless I'm going for the kill so I was wondering if Thunderlord's is a better option.

A little something I would like to point out is that I play Kindred mid/ top! Never on jungle, so please do consider that on your opinion.

Comment: I'd recommend trying out both and then seeing which one you think is better, perhaps your playstyle/builds would suit one over the other.

Comment: Just try it out and see how you like it. Thunderlords is way stronger in the early game, so if you go aggressive there it can give you an advantage and you can snowball from there. If you only farm and build a lot of as fervor is better late game

Comment: I think if you're mid against a typical mid-laner (LB, Ahri, Annie, Lux, Zed, etc), Thunderlord's will give you a lot more early game burst that retains its value over the course of the game vs squishy targets. If you're top against a typical top-laner (Renekton, Darius, Malphite, Fiora, etc), Fervor is going to be more valuable since you will probably be tied up in more sustained fights. Either way, play what you feel comfortable with, but don't discount the burst potential of Thunderlord's, especially early.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you said, it is hard to answer this without giving an opinion... But i'll try my best :

Considering you're a top/mid laner, Fervor of battle is a better option. you can  keep your stacks on and poke the ennemy laner every 5s roless, which will give you overall higher damages compared to thunderlord.

If you want to try a Burst playstyle, you should go for thunderlord, but this is more of a jungler option, since you gives at max 4 or 5 hit on a gank.

The other thing to consider is the T5 Mastery. When you reach fervor of battle, you get the 7% armor penetration, which is huge, especially for a laner. The T5 on the thunderlord branch aren't quite as good as this one for an ad exclusive laner.

All these reasons are why you should keep going on fervor as a laner, and maybe switch to thunderlord in jungle.

PS/opinion : You shouldn't play her mid or top, that's not her role and there are more usefull champions on these posts !

Comment: I don't know why everyone believes that Fervor gains stacks when you hit minions, but it got nerfed on that regard quite a few patches ago so now it gains stacks only when you hit champions, which is huge since you can't stack it nowhere near as easy. Which made me wondering if Thunderlord's is a better option.
PS. It really does not matter to me where the champion got designed to play as long as they perform well on the lane I'm playing them. Let's not forget that Orianna was originally designed to be a support - I don't remember the last time I saw her fulfilling that role.

Comment: And you only gain 1 stack per attack, unlike melee which gain 2 stacks. And for only playing Kindred in the jungle, her sustain, kite and range make her extremely annoying to play against no matter what lane she's in. Don't waste that by jungling. Shes by far one of the strongest ADC early game due to her damage and sustain.

Comment: Yeh indeed i fogot they changed fervor of battle recently since I almost never uses that mastery, but it doesn't really change it that much. Even 4 stacks are enough to make it worth, without forgetting the 7% armor penetration of the first branch. And as you said yourself, it is more of an habit, if you're a poky player, maybe thunderlord will fit you better, but if you're trading straight up to kill, fervor is obviously better... And by the way I don't know what elo you are but kindred top or mid won't do anything diamond or higher, it got too many weaknesses on a lane.

Comment: @Bl00dylicious Her jungle health, clear speed, and ganking ability all lend to her being an incredible jungler. It's also the fastest way of getting her passive stacked. I strongly recommend jungle over other roles (not that she does particularly poorly anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I Will give an answer Based on how the meta and the Masteries work (29-02-2016)

### Thunderlord's Decree:

Gives you a higher burst, but doesn't do much, if you are planning to have prolonged fights it won't help that much because you will most likely only proc it once in the whole fight, however, when you are ahead(Something that is easy to do on Kindred Jungle) it will give you a nice help to quickly kill your targets(Unless they are Tanks), and in lane may give you some more trading potential.

### Fervor of Battle:

Allows you to have more damage the longer the fight goes on(Something that can happen a lot of times since Kindred isn't the best assassin) and if you go Devourer (or another High AS build) you will stack it fairly quickly in a fight and it might give you a lot more help than ThunderLord's since it sinergizes a bit better with Kindred's overall kit (Kite and high mobility).

### Recommendation:

If you are gonna play her Jungle i would honestly take Strength of the Ages(In this meta) since it will give you more HP to stay healthy in fights and you can stack it fairly quickly, if not it truly depends on their's and your's TeamComp.

For instance, if you have a kite composition, Fervor will be of more use since you will stack it and deal extra damage in the fight.

If you have a Teamfight and Pick composition, Thunderlord's would be better since it will give you higher burst.

### Final remarks:

I would say just take Strength of the Ages ( If you are gonna play jungle) because of the overall benefit it gives you, but if you lane with Kindred, it depends, are you gonna be looking at long and Drawn out fights in your lane or quick trades? Hope i was able to help